# Superstrength and hypertrophy

Tags: super-powers

So it's fairly well established that to build bigger muscles you cause damage to muscles commonly by (lifting weights) and your body repairs these and grows bigger muscles. So how do superheroes with super strength like Luke Cake for example get to be be absolutely jacked?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. If you are looking for "in story" explanation, you might better ask in the appropriate SE. To better understand what this community is about, take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Should Luke Cake be [Luke Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Lex. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. We operate on a one-question-one-best-answer policy; in other words, site users need to be able to rate one answer as more capable of addressing the question than another. Because different supers get their abilities in different ways, and even the mechanics of being a super differ from franchise to franchise, this question has been put on hold for being _too story-based_.